# Change in JavaScript function depending on value from HTML form

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JS & HTML and I'm working with code written by someone else so I don't fully grasp it. I'll try my best to ask a proper question.

In HTML I have

```
 <select id="temp-option" name="temp-option" value="{{temp-option}}">
          <option value="Water">Water temperature</option>
          <option value="Air">Air temperature</option>
 </select>
```

I then get value chosen by the user in JS with  `var tempOption = document.getElementById("temp-option");` and want to change the variables in a function using this. It should be simple but the code is a bit above my understanding so I can't figure out how to get my specific case working.

```
function plot(){
    //Leave out what I think is irrelevant.
    let temperatures1 = mapping((f) => {return {time: time_since(f.DateAndTime, startTime), temp: f.WaterTemperature}}, estimation.EstimationData);
    let temperatures2 = mapping((f) => {return {time: time_since(f.DateAndTime, startTime), temp: f.WaterTemp}}, tempData);
}
```

So the water temperatures are stored in two JSON strings (from my understanding) and are called on by different names so I need to send different variables depending on if its for temperatures1 or temperatures2.

I tried to do this with if statements.

```
if(tempOption.value == "Water"){
   tempChoice = ["f.WaterTemperature", "f.WaterTemp"]
}
if(tempOption.value == "Air"){
   tempChoice = ["f.AirTemperature", "f.AirTemp"]
}
```

and then swapping the xxx in "temp: xxx" in temperatures with `tempChoice[1]` or `tempChoice[2]`:

```
let temperatures1 = mapping((f) => {return {time: time_since(f.DateAndTime, startTime), temp: tempChoice[0]}}, estimation.EstimationData);`
```

Here's map if it's needed to understand.

```
function map(f, xs) {
    var xs2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    xs2.push(f(xs[i]));
    }
    return xs2;
}
```

Some help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this solution would be recommended by anyone experienced with programming. I might have to redo it later when I'm more knowledgeable.

The solution which worked for me was incredibly easy, I just had to change how I call the JS object. At first I used `objectName.property` as you can see in the question. Replacing "property" here can't be done with the strings I produce in the if-statements. When you instead access the object´s property with the use of `objectName["property"]` the property name is presented as a string and can therefore be easily replaced with another string. In my case `objectName[tempChoice[0]]` & `objectName[tempChoice[1]]`.

Bear in mind though, this is probably a solution to a problem which exists only due to bad programming to start with. If you know another solution, my guess is, use that one, and please do share.

Answer (score 0):

You propably should do some Js tutorials. Because whats you are doing are some "critical" faults. Look into how Json and Arrays are working.

I didnt fully undestand the code but this will not work:

```
if(tempOption.value == Water){
tempChoice = ["temp: f.WaterTemperature", "temp: f.WaterTemp"]
}
```

because you are creating an array and this array contains two strings. And i highly doubt, that this is what you want to do. I guess you want JS bject literals inside your array. Something like this:

```
tempChoice =[{"temp":f.WaterTemperature},{"temp":f.WaterTemp}]
```

Also you are comparing the value with a non string

```
if(tempOption.value ==="Water")
```

should be what you probably want to do

**Edit**
Btw, if not necessary I would not use this code. I think the naming is really bad. e.g. "f" is normally a function that is going to be called (wich the author did in the function map) but inside the mapping function call "f" is used as a parameter that contains objects. This makes the code even harder to undestand

Comment: You keep referring to object literals as "JSON objects".  Those are JS object literals.  JSON is a string.

Comment: Edited question to correct some errors I had made when asking. 

I thought about the json-objects at first too but the return in map won't accept the text unless it's "temp: xxx", that's why I'm trying to swap out only the xxx with tempChoice[0]. But this is obviously incorrect. Do I need to change the whole structure of my temperature variables or the map function or is there a way to actually swap out the "temp: xxx" that will work?